# How do you configure VSCode jsconfig for React?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to make VSCode to work smoothly with my React project. I am refering to the ability to click into a component and go inside, peek at the component or propose stuff for auto completion (intellisense).

I have this so far:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es2019",
      "jsx": "react",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@Reducers/*": ["./src/reducers/*"],
        "@Selectors/*": ["./src/selectors/*"],
        "@Components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
        "@App/*": ["./src/components/App/*"],
        "@Footer/*": ["./src/components/Footer/*"],
        "@Header/*": ["./src/components/Header/*"],
    }
  },
  "include" : ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "config", ".vscode"]
}
```

I do not use CRA.

Any idea why is not working? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance and regards

edit: it seems that with module:commonjs instead of es6 is working better, any idea of why is this? I am using es6 imports!

edit2: the reason is explained here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24715

Answer (score 2):

We need more information about you project. but, All most problem about absolute path is base url.

If you used Webpack, Read [Webpack - Alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). and then read this too. [Github CRA Path Issues](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118)

#### Examples

I used this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const path = require('path');

// Webpack Config
export default {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ['@']: path.join(root, 'src')
    }   
  }
}
```

If you have a root path, this is easy to change paths. So I recommend that `don't use multiple '@' pahts` too.

#### Refs

- Webpack - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias
- CRA:Github - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5118

Comment: Links can disappear or change. Since we want the answers here to be durable, quote the part from the link that seems to be relevant and explain why the link is important.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What else do you need to know about my project? I use Webpack and my aliases work fine, it is only the VS Code part that does not seem to get the aliases well.

Comment: @JavierGuzman I think about error message or other things(configuration info).
But, I don't know why is this did not working now. :(

Comment: I will put later my folder structure in case it helps...So far I have edited before saying that using module: commonjs seems to work a partially...no idea of why if I am using es6!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution at the end was to use module: commonjs instead of module: es6

This is explained here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24715

Quote:
"In a jsconfig, the module option only changes how paths are resolved"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install extensions for ReactJs like: `ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets` or `Simple React Snippets`. Try these two.

Comment: Then try the 2nd-one. It may help.